# Android Diffie hellman BN_mod_inverse 0306E06C error

Tags: android, algorithm, security, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement Diffie Hellman Algo between client and server. For that I am using below code to generate Public key

Shared p,g and public key from server end

```
DH p:E1C66AFAB0E8518914EE1E58DDD9B337
DH g:05
DH public key(95D1FAFBFE8096BFF6C528A571B307B4)
```

Android code below

```
final BigInteger p = new
BigInteger("E1C66AFAB0E8518914EE1E58DDD9B337", 16);//convert hex to BigInteger
final BigInteger g = new BigInteger("05", 16);//convert hex to BigInteger
final int l = 128;

KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
keyGen.initialize(new DHParameterSpec(p, g, l));
KeyPair ackp = keyGen.generateKeyPair(); 
PrivateKey priKey = ackp.getPrivate();
PublicKey pubKey = ackp.getPublic();
```

Output: pubKey value

```
OpenSSLDHPublicKey{
        Y=8d664db67d53602ef3f2eb5dce616fb9,
        P=b7f51eb91d787dbcd74ab1d752abf207,
        G=5}
```

So far, so good but when I am using public key(95D1FAFBFE8096BFF6C528A571B307B4 shared by server end) to generate symmetric/final key

Code:

```
final BigInteger p = new
    BigInteger("95D1FAFBFE8096BFF6C528A571B307B4", 16);//convert hex to BigInteger
    final BigInteger g = new BigInteger("05", 16);//convert hex to BigInteger
    final int l = 128;

    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
    keyGen.initialize(new DHParameterSpec(p, g, l));
    KeyPair ackp = keyGen.generateKeyPair(); 
    PrivateKey priKey = ackp.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pubKey = ackp.getPublic();
```

I am getting following error:

```
12-23 12:16:35.801: W/System.err(12512): java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0306E06C:bignum routines:BN_mod_inverse:no inverse
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated :)